# Construct embedding in Euclidean space for arbitrary connection

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, fiber-bundles

In this [What is the affine connection, and what is the intuition behind/for affine connection?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145255/what-is-the-affine-connection-and-what-is-the-intuition-behind-for-affine-conne/2145287#2145287), it says that in mapping of Euclidean spaces $R^n \rightarrow R^n$, we have $\nabla_Y X (p) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{X(t + Y(p)) - X(p)}{t}$ and we can check that it is a connection.

My question is that:

For arbitrary connection on a manifold $M$, can we construct an Euclidean embedding of arbitrary dimension, $M \rightarrow R^n$, s.t. the affine connection is compatible with the addition algebraic operation? i.e. (1) $\nabla_Y X (p) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{X(t + Y(p)) - X(p)}{t}$ in the Euclidean embedding induces an addition algebraic structure $t + Y(p)$ on the original manifold $M$

(2) the connections on two manifolds are the same action on the tangent bundle?

Comment: This doesn't even make sense for submanifolds of $\Bbb R^n$ to start with.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I edited it as mapping between Euclidean space of the same dimension $R^n \rightarrow R^n$ rather than arbitrary embedding of manifolds. If it is $R^2 \rightarrow R^3$, then it has to be $\nabla_Y X(p) = \pi(\lim (\frac{X(t+Y(p)) - X(p)}{t})$ by projecting it onto the tangent space of the submanifold of $R^3$.

Comment: This is defined only if $X$ is defined on a tubular neighborhood of $M$ to start with.